# He will join us soon / He will be joining us soon

Tags: british-english, spoken-english

> He will join us soon.
>   He will be joining us soon.

This is  little confusing, both options seem correct to me. Please explain.

Comment: They're both perfectly valid, as are *He is joining us soon* and *He joins us soon*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are correct and they mean the same thing. I would say the difference is esthetic.

Answer (score 2):

I find a very slight difference between them: "will be joining" is about his intention, whereas "will join" is about future events, not about anybody's intention.

In  this case, there is no effective difference, since the event is probably volitional for him; but consider

> He will fall off that ladder in a minute.
>
> ? He will be falling off that ladder in a minute.

The second is much less likely (and possibly suggests that this will be the working out of fate: not his intention, of course, but someone's - or something's - intention).